# curl post not working, but postman works fine

Tags: curl

I have a postman request, working fine.

But, when I copy the curl code from postman, I get a http 500 from the API source. Source uses http basic auth

```
curl --basic --request POST \
--url https://ws.nls.fi/ktjkii/wfs-2015/wfs \
--header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
--header 'postman-token: 25017565-f897-7727-f42e-asdqwe123' \
--data '<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:ktjkiiwfs="http://xml.nls.fi/ktjkiiwfs/2010/02" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" \
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" \
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" \
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" \
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs \
http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><wfs:Query typeName="ktjkiiwfs:PalstanTietoja" srsName="epsg:3067">\
<ogc:Filter><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>ktjkiiwfs:rekisteriyksikonKiinteistotunnus</ogc:PropertyName>\
<ogc:Literal>My_number</ogc:Literal>\
</ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>\
</ogc:Filter>\
</wfs:Query>\
</wfs:GetFeature>' \
-v -u my_user:my_pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Postman seems to automatically append XML header.

When I added:

```
-H "Content-Type:application/xml"
```

in my code it worked

Comment: I am faced same issue. And Even though I settled content type, it is not working.

Comment: Copy your curl I guess so we can see